# Vue routing - how to use clean URLs with /:slug for multiple components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm looking for a solution to get the current situation:

- Pages - domain.com/page-name (example: /contact)
- Categories - domain.com/category-name (example: /blog)

With Vue I'm unable to create this with the slug as a prop.

```
  {
    path: '/:slug',
    name: 'Page',
    props: true,
    component: () => import('../views/Page.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/:slug', // /category/:slug will work but I would like /:slug als path
    name: 'Category',
    props: true,
    component: () => import('../views/Category.vue')
  }
```

I know that a different path wil fix this, for example: '/category/:slug' but I'm looking for a way to create clean URLs without a prefix. Is this possible?

Comment: You are absolutely free to choose the path of each and every route - as long as there are no 2 routes with the same path. So instead of `/:slug` just use `/page-title-first` and `/page-title-second` and so on.

Comment: I didn't explained it very well. The reason I'm using /:slug is because the data is coming from a CMS through an axios request. So static slug names can't be used.

Comment: Then you should prepend some static text in front - e.g. `/news/:slug` or `/pages/:slug`. Routes can have parameters - but the route itself must be static.

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to avoid that. It looks like it's not possible in a clean way. Currently I fixed it by using a static URL for the parent page. This creates multiple extra views so it's not the best solution.